# How to avoid writing `await` every time

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

When I use aiologger, I have to write `await logger` many times.

For [example](https://async-worker.github.io/aiologger/usage.html#lazy-initialization),

```
import asyncio
from aiologger import Logger


async def main():
    logger = Logger.with_default_handlers(name='my-logger')

    await logger.debug("debug at stdout")
    await logger.info("info at stdout")

    await logger.warning("warning at stderr")
    await logger.error("error at stderr")
    await logger.critical("critical at stderr")

    await logger.shutdown()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
loop.close()
```

It would be great if I could write something like `al` instead of `await logger`.

Comment: Wow, that’s an awful library design: logging calls should be zero-overhead and _fast_: doing IO on every call is… dumb.

Comment: @Dai I am also looking at https://www.zopatista.com/python/2019/05/11/asyncio-logging/ Not understanding how it actually works.

Comment: @Dai Await doesn't mean that every logging call does IO, but that it _can_ do IO. By its nature, logging must occasionally write to disk or network, and making them non-async means that they either block when they do so, or that the IO is completely decoupled from the logging calls. The first option leads to IO block the whole event loop, and the latter causes unbounded memory usage if logging calls outpace the IO (which is not impossible in programs in debug mode with high logging output). Awaiting the logging calls in something called **aio** logger is basically a must, not awful design!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I've written about this -- https://coxley.org/logging/#logging-over-the-network

Please don't accept a logging interface like this.

You can't avoid using `await` to yield the event loop. You just can't. But you can leverage existing features to do I/O outside of the main thread and still use asyncio. You just start a second event loop in that thread.

[image: diagram]

## Example

I don't like to recommend third-party libs in answers, but `janus.Queue` is important here. Makes it easier to bridge between non-asyncio writers (eg: Log Handler) and asyncio readers (the flusher).

**Note 1**: If you don't actually need asyncio-compatible I/O from the flusher, use stdlib `queue.Queue`, remove the async-closure, and get rid of the second loop.

**Note 2**: This example has both an unbounded queue and does I/O for every message. Add an interval and/or message threshold for flushing to be production-ready. Depending on your system, decide whether you accept memory growth for log bursts, drop logs, or block the main code-path.

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import time
import threading
import typing as t

# pip install --user janus
import janus

LOG = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Queue must be created within the event loop it will be used from. Start as
# None since this will not be the main thread.
_QUEUE: t.Optional[janus.Queue] = None

class IOHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # This is set from the flusher thread
        global _QUEUE
        while _QUEUE is None:
            time.sleep(0.01)
        self.q = _QUEUE.sync_q
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        self.q.put(record)

def flusher():
    async def run():
        global _QUEUE
        if _QUEUE is None:
            _QUEUE = janus.Queue()
        # Upload record instead of print
        # Perhaps flush every n-seconds w/ buffer for upper-bound on inserts.
        q = _QUEUE.async_q
        while True:
            record = await q.get()
            print("woohoo, doing i/o:", record.msg)

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(run())

def foo():
    print("foo")

def bar():
    print("bar")

async def baz():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("baz")

async def main():
    threading.Thread(target=flusher, daemon=True).start()
    LOG.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    LOG.addHandler(IOHandler())

    foo()
    LOG.info("starting program")
    LOG.info("doing some stuff")
    LOG.info("mighty cool")
    bar()
    await baz()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: https://rob-blackbourn.medium.com/how-to-use-python-logging-queuehandler-with-dictconfig-1e8b1284e27a the code is not working in my machine.Can you please check if it works.

Comment: The trouble with this approach is that the janus queue you're creating is unbounded. If the program is logging faster than the IO can flush them out (which can happen to programs with a large number of debug logs), it will accumulate log calls in memory without bounds. That might not be a big deal for many programs, but should be clearly documented.

Comment: @blueray: What code are you asking about? The random Medium link you shared or the answer's example? Confirmed the answer works. The Medium article, well... that's a lot to digest and not sure how it fits in here. :)

Comment: @user4815162342: The example was intentionally simple but I'll clarify. I'd still rather logging be delayed / backed up than flushing halt main logic. I've systems perform 2-50x more poorly just because it was located in another region from the primary database and they didn't flush out-of-band. :)